# Clarify this default rspec controller test and make it pass

Tags: testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is the default test generated with a scaffold I created.

```
  describe "PUT update", focus: true do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "updates the requested purchase_order" do
        current_valid_attr = valid_attributes
        purchase_order = PurchaseOrder.create! current_valid_attr
        # Assuming there are no other purchase_orders in the database, this
        # specifies that the PurchaseOrder created on the previous line
        # receives the :update_attributes message with whatever params are
        # submitted in the request.
        # PurchaseOrder.any_instance.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({'these' => 'params'})
        # put :update, :id => purchase_order.id, :purchase_order => {'these' => 'params'}
        PurchaseOrder.any_instance.should_receive(:update_attributes).with(current_valid_attr)
        put :update, :id => purchase_order.id, :purchase_order => current_valid_attr
      end
```

The problem is I don't understand **what it is supposed to do** and I can't **make it pass** with the correct attributes. Here's the error when I ran the test

```
Failures:

      1) PurchaseOrdersController PUT update with valid params updates the requested purchase_order
         Failure/Error: put :update, :id => purchase_order.id, :purchase_order => current_valid_attr
           #<PurchaseOrder:0x007fe3027521e0> received :update_attributes with unexpected arguments
             expected: ({"id"=>nil, "supplier_id"=>1, "no"=>1305, "no_rujukan"=>"Guiseppe Abshire", "jenis"=>"P", "mula_on"=>Sat, 23 Aug 2003 14:11:42 MYT +08:00, "created_at"=>nil, "updated_at"=>nil})
                  got: ({"id"=>nil, "supplier_id"=>"1", "no"=>"1305", "no_rujukan"=>"Guiseppe Abshire", "jenis"=>"P", "mula_on"=>"2003-08-23 14:11:42 +0800", "created_at"=>nil, "updated_at"=>nil})
```

Thanks in advance.

**valid_attributes**

```
  def valid_attributes
    Factory.build(:purchase_order).attributes
  end
```

**The factory**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :purchase_order do
      association           :supplier
      sequence(:no)         { |n| Random.rand(1000...9999) }
      sequence(:no_rujukan) { |n| Faker::Name.name }
      sequence(:jenis)      { |n| PurchaseOrder::PEROLEHAN[Random.rand(0..3).to_i] }
      sequence(:mula_on)    { |n| Random.rand(10.year).ago }
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you show definition of `valid_attributes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This test checks that when request comes to `PurchaseOrdersController#update` action `update_attributes` method for one of `PurchaseOrder` models is called and request parameters are properly passed to this method.

The problem here (as stated by error message) is that `update_attributes` is called with hash of attributes that has all values of type `String`. That's because all values of `params` hash (containing all request parameters) that is most likely used in `update` action are strings.

On the other hand your `current_valid_attr` hash contains values of different types like `Fixnum` and `Time`. And when time comes to compare expected and received values you get an error, because, for example, `no` attribute was expected to be Fixnum `1305`, but after submitting request it was converted to string and `update_attributes` received String `'1305'` instead.

One of the ways to fix the problem is to ensure that all values in `current_valid_attr` are strings:

```
no = 1305
mula_on = Time.now
# explicitly convert all attributes to String
current_valid_attr = { :no => no.to_s, :mula_on => mula_on.to_s }
```

**Updated**

There is [`paramify_values`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior/paramify_values) method that can be used in tests to convert hash of parameters to the same form that will be received by controller in `params` hash.

Comment: I'm using FactoryGirl to generate the valid attribute, does this means I need to explicitly convert the attributes one by one?

Comment: You can try using [`paramify_values`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior/paramify_values) method. It is used internally to convert values of all parameters passed to `get`, `post` and other request methods to strings. Try this: `paramify_values(Factory.build(:purchase_order).attributes)`.